# ionChange event firing twice with dynamic ion-segment

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Here's the console log

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRMxu.png)

It's firing once with the static ion-change segment, but twice with dynamic, here's my code so you can understand it better.

```
<ion-segment *ngIf='!isLoading' scrollable="true" value="all" (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)" style="place-content: center;">
  <ion-segment-button value="all">
    <ion-label>All</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button [value]="c.payload.doc.data().name" *ngFor="let c of categorys">
    <ion-label>{{ c.payload.doc.data().name }}</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

segment change code

```
 segmentChanged(ev: any) {
    if (ev.detail.value === 'all') {
      this.feedSub = this.feedService.getAll().subscribe(results => {
        this.allposts = results.sort((a, b) => a.dateCreated <= b.dateCreated ? 1 : -1);
        console.log(ev.detail.value);
      });
    }else {
      this.feedSub = this.feedService.getAll().subscribe(results => {
        this.allposts = results.sort((a, b) => a.dateCreated <= b.dateCreated ? 1 : -1);
      });
      this.allposts = this.allposts.filter((post) => {
        console.log(ev.detail.value);
         // console.log(post.category.name.match(ev.detail.value));
        return post.category.name.match(ev.detail.value);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tested your code on stackblitz and it is firing ionChange only once (no matter if one chooses the static button or one of the buttons generated by the `ngFor`). See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nvt4ts?file=pages/home/home.ts

Comment: can you make you own stackblitz so we can see the problem happening?

Comment: Now i added two more items, and i got it fired 4 times, (last time I only got 2 items on my feed page that's why it was only firing 2 times, I guess this is about how I'm fetching data from firestore) I will check again, thank you for your time btw.

Comment: I can't figure this out, it fires at how many posts I have on my feed.

Comment: can you edit your post and include the code of `segmentChanged()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is probably working as expected, i.e., the `ionChange` is firing only once.

The several messages you see in console are caused by this `console.log` inside the filter function:

```
this.allposts = this.allposts.filter((post) => {
  console.log(ev.detail.value);
  return post.category.name.match(ev.detail.value);
});
```

When you call filter and supply a function, that function will be executed once for each post in `allposts`. Thats why the message is being outputed in the console n times, being n the total number of posts.

**What you may change in your code:**

1 - Place the `console.log(ev.detail.value);` on top of the `segmentChange` function (and not inside the filter).

2 - It is not related to you question, but it is recommended to call the `filter` only after the subscription is fired and the `this.allposts` value is setted:

```
this.feedSub = this.feedService.getAll().subscribe(results => {
    this.allposts = results.sort((a, b) => a.dateCreated <= b.dateCreated ? 1 : -1);

    this.allposts = this.allposts.filter((post) => {
      return post.category.name.match(ev.detail.value);
    });
});
```